# Body {background-color} not working in external css?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, background-color

I am not able to change background color using an external style sheet. when i try this with internal style sheet it works perfect. 
Here is the code.

```
ext1.css
<style>
body{
   background-color: red;
}
ul{
   color:green;
}
:link{
    color:aquamarine;
}
p{
   font-family:"arial";
    font-size:20px;
}
</style>


HTML DOC

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Defining external style sheet</title>
<link href="ext1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li> <a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="#News">News</a></li>
<li> <a href="#Contact us">Contact</a></li> 
<li> <a href="#About">About</a></li>
</ul>
<p> NOTE: We use href="#" for test links , in real web sites we will use URL's </p>
```

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @HarshSanghani considering that it works inline, i dont think it's necessary.

Comment: @AmritPalSingh are you sure that the path (relative url) to the script is correct? Can you verify it from the console?

Comment: Remove `<style>` tags from your css.

Comment: @VenkataKrishna thanks after removing <style> tags it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't have the HTML `<style>` tags in your external CSS.

Your CSS file should look like this:

```
body {
   background-color: red;
}
ul {
   color: green;
}
:link {
   color: aquamarine;
}
p {
   font-family: "arial";
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I believe that is not the case. The OP is referring to only body no taking the background color. OP has just put that to show the code, but I don't think so this is the issue.

Comment: If the body was not having its background applied, the only possible problem could be that the css file was not being parsed properly. And having html style tags in your css will do that.

Comment: on his example - there are missing the closing tags for `body` and `html` but thats not the issue (but should be fixed). if i create a file with the html and external css without the surrounding `<style>` it works. with surrounding `<style>` on ext1.css it doesn't work.

Comment: But then this would have effect on other elements also and not only the body background.

Comment: @NathanL The reason only background of `body` had this effect was because the tag was placed right above `body` in css. 
Here, it is not the tag `<style>` specifically that is causing the issue. You place any letter or character just above any css declaration(like `body` in our case) and the respective style wouldn't be rendered in your page.